# How to inspect and optimize closures in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, serialization, closures

[Apache Spark](https://spark.apache.org/) computes [closures of functions applied to RDDs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#understanding-closures-docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#understanding-closures-) to send them to executor nodes.

This serialization has a cost, so I would like to ensure that the closures Spark generates are as small as they can be. For instance, it is possible that functions needlessly refer to a large serializable object which would get serialized in the closure, without actually being required for the computation.

Are there any tools to inspect the contents of the closures sent to executors? Or any other technique to optimize them?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of a tool to inspect closures, but one technique to optimize serialization costs is to use broadcast variables (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#broadcast-variables), which will serialize and send a copy of the object to each executor. This is useful for static, readonly objects (i.e; a lookup table/dictionary), and it could save on serialization costs. For example, if we have 100 partitions and 10 executor nodes (10 partitions per executor), rather than serializing and sending the object to each partition (100x), it will only be serialized and sent to each executor (10x); once the object is sent to an executor for one partition, the other partitions will refer to the in-memory copy.

Hope this helps!